# What algorithm solves this problem? Non-linear measuring tape

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

[image: The measuring tape]

A measuring tape is marked at 0, 5, 15 and 40. The distances between each mark are marked on top. At what distances should I mark 1 through 4, as well as 6-14 and 16-39? My math knowledge does not cover this.
Obviously 0-1 is the largest distance, then 1-2, 2-3 and so on.
Which algorithm is appropriate here? I do not even know what to search for. I tried some online regression calculators (logarithmic) but I failed to find a solution for this.
Also, English is not my first language. I'm sorry if anything is confusing above.

Comment: This is a fancy form of the "guess what number I'm thinking about" game. There are literally infinitely many rules the problem author could've used to assign the marks he has, and although some might be more probable than others, nine are more correct than others. So as long as you find _one rule_ that fits, I'd say you're good. I'd go with polynomial regression, just for fun.

Comment: I meant to say that _none_ are more correct then any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An nbubis answered, many models could fit the data and the problem here is that you have very very few data points.

Using as a model  $y=a x^b$ and minimizing the sum of  the squares of absolute errors, I obtained  $a=41.8586$ and $b=0.259482$; for these parameters, we obtain values of $0.00$, $63.55$, $84.52$ and $109.02$.

Minimizing the sum of  the squares of relative errors, I obtained  $a=40.8547$ and $b=0.267670$; for these parameters, we obtain values of $0.00$, $62.85$, $84.34$ and $109.66$.

It could be very good if you could have more data points.

Comment: Thanks! Your and @yves-daoust answer looks precise enough.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a particular algorithm, but you can try fitting the points to different curves. You basically want to find $y(x)$, where you have:
$$y(0)=0,\ y(5)=62,\ y(15)=87,\ y(40)=108$$
By looking at the curve you can see that the slope decreases sharply though the function is increasing. Thus, assuming the function is monotonic, either $y(x)=Ax^b, 0<b<1$ or $y(x)=A\log(bx)$ are candidate models, though of course, **infinitely many more complex functions may fit at least as well**.

Using a least squares algorithm, I found:
$$y(x)\approx 0.301 \times e^{0.0452 x}$$
Which although it gives $0$ at $x\approx 0.3$ instead of zero, gives a nice overall fit.

Using this function you can fill in the blanks.

Comment: 0.301×e^(0.0452×5)≈0.3078, not 62. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Fitting any empirical model on so little data is indeed a random guesswork. (Anyway, I would certainly not think of a logarithmic or exponential model, as the first data point is $(0,0)$).

To get any sensible answer, it is better that you explain how this data is generated.

With no better information, natural cubic spline interpolation should be appropriate.

Comment: This is what I did: I put the x (distances) and the y (tape marks) in a graph and plotted a smooth (cubic spline) line between them. I then checked where the lines intersected and got the distances for the missing marks. [graph](http://imgur.com/IWJ7NuU) However, this is not very pleasing, for instance when checking non-integer tape marks (e.g y=0.25).

Comment: Not very pleasing ??? Do you mean not convenient ?

Comment: Not very convenient. A formula which takes x and y would be more precise and practical.

Comment: Well, use a sw package that supports cubic spline interpolation.